# what are the proper chmod settings for the Media folder?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

Magento 1.9.x

We were troubleshooting something and changed the permissions on the Media folder.

What are the proper chmod permissions on Media, var and the log (in var) folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

700 permissions (drwx------) for the media/ and var/ directories give full control (that is, read/write/execute) to the owner and no permissions to anyone else.

600 permissions (-rw-------) for files in the media/ and var/ directories enable the web server user to write to them and to overwrite them.

```
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} +
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} +
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} +
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} +
```

Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html